# c# ProcessMemoryReaderLib not working

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using ProcessMemoryReaderLib;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
```

This seems to always return the error

> "Error  1   The type or namespace name 'ProcessMemoryReaderLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\giacomo\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs   10  7   WindowsFormsApplication1
> "

Answer (score 1):

In your `Solution Explorer`, right click your `References` > `Add Reference` then click `Browse`, then find and select your `.dll` File and add it to your references. You can't include a library in your project with `using` if you don't include your assembly.

Take a look at here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[image]Just build the project after adding the reference of the ProcessMemoryReaderLib.dll in your project,then use using ProcessMemoryReaderLib; in your class file